# boolean expression syntax checking

Tags: reference-request, compilers, parsers

i am trying to formulate an algorithm for syntax checking for simple boolean expression like (var1 = 10) or (var2 > 100). 
evaluation part seems to be easy as i will convert infix to postfix and evaluate postfix without 'paren()'.

i am not fully sure which method should i be using.

can any one point me to a book with algorithm or a link.

Comment: Take a look at [context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Algebraic_expressions) and some [parsing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Parsing_algorithms)

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is part of the area of knowledge known as *compiler theory*, specifically *parsing*. One of the classical books is the [dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). Parsing and evaluating expressions like yours is usually done in three interlocked steps:

1. Lexical analysis. This part is in charge of converting the input into a sequence of "lexemes". It will convert your example into the lexemes "(" VARIABLE "=" NUMBER ")" "or" "(" VARIABLE ">" NUMBER ")". This step is implemented using regular automata.
2. Syntax analysis. This part construct a parse tree of your expression. In your case, the parse tree (generated using [Miles Shang's online tool](http://mshang.ca/syntree/)) will be:
   [image: Parse tree]
   This step is implemented using context-free languages, either using a table-based approach or using recursive descent.
3. Semantic analysis. In your case, this part will evaluate the expression recursively using the parse tree, making use of *attributes* stored at the meta-lexemes VARIABLE and NUMBER.